# How to have PyCharm deployment and local+remote git work together

Tags: git, pycharm

When developing, non professionally, a Django website with PyCharm, I usually setup a local git repository and deploy (automatically) to the remote web server. This allows me to have everything up and running, but with the additional safety of version control.

The problem is that my colleagues use VSCode, which instead uses a remote git repository and directly works on the remote server.

My problem is that when I change one file (let's say add an `x` to a readme file), this file is modified on the remote server. Then I push my local change. The remote git is in the older state with a modification which is exactly equal to the one that `git pull` would provide. But `git pull` refuses to overwrite.

The ugly thing is that if I use

```
git stash push
git pull
git stash pop
```

I get a conflict. But if you show the diff, you get two identical files. So I have to manually accept the changes even if they give the same identical file.

I know I'm misunderstanding something, but still I cannot understand how to deal with this.